# How to show mini controller at bottom or persistent media controls like spotify or Google music in whole application

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, exoplayer

I'm developing an app that can play video from youtube or other live streaming, if a user pressed back/home button, a user can hear the audio-only, and then they can back to see the video again. I have created a service that holds player and does all things. In my whole application, there are many activities and fragments.

**Question:**

I want to show a mini controller at the bottom of every screen while something is playing, you can refer applications like Spotify, google play, and other music applications. These applications show a mini controller when a user leaves their main media player activity/fragment. How I can achieve that feature in my current application. Note: my application contains many activities and fragment. So there is not only one main activity.

**What I have tried to find a possible solution:**

1. First [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154401/how-can-i-add-persistent-media-controls-like-apollo-or-google-music), here they are suggesting to use only one activity in the whole application and others are fragments only, that's not possible in my case.
2. [Collapsing Bottom Bar (like Google Music) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32602894/collapsing-bottom-bar-like-google-music-in-android): here they are suggesting to about collapsing and expanding the bottom bar, I am looking for this animation too, but one more thing is that how I can persistent bottom bar in a whole application when the user navigates to other screens.
3. [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel), this library will helpful for me? To make a persistent bottom bar throughout the application?

Can anybody please tell me how they are handling this thing throughout the whole application?

You can find the below image, which gives you a clear idea, what exactly I am looking for.

**MiniController image:**

[image]

Comment: this is better answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21658058/build-play-music-like-interface?noredirect=1&lq=1